# prometheus for extracting SPARQL endpoint metrics

Tags: http, sparql, prometheus

I want to extract some of the stats (QpS or number of http requests etc.) of a server through prometheus. The server is basically an **RDF SPARQL enpoint**. Is it possible to do it through prometheus? If yes, which type of prometheus toll i.e. **blackbox_exporter** or **graphite_exporter** or **haproxy_exporter** or any other is the suitable toll for doing it?

Comment: that depends on the endpoint if it has such an interface as you by the way already know from the Jena mailing list: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/202102.mbox/%3CCANJH4dryhz7W%3D%3DTOAVOiM7N8b89ka6ifTThudSEj1_J90Ai_iQ%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: I will further ask; I can see the metrics of jena-fuseki server through `http://localhost:3030/$/metrics` in the browser, but when I insert                               `- job_name: 'Fuseki'
static_configs:
- targets: ['localhost:3030/ds/$']` in the **prometheus.yml** file, then the prometheus service gets down after restarting. But when I tries only `loclahost:3030` instead of `loclahost:3030/ds/$` then the prometheus service repsponded but the target endpoint i.e `localhost:3030` is shown as **down**. Any suggestion please